# Interception content from eval()

Tags: php, eval, bots

When im using eval() function in PHP i can't see it's answer (because of using it in Telegram bot), so is there any way to get the error/response of eval() function?

Comment: for `response of eval`, you mean the output that will be generated from it?

Comment: Yes. Error or response of function called in eval()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return something from the evaluated code and catch that return value from the call to `eval()`, like this:

```
$returnValue = eval('return sqrt(2);');
var_dump($returnValue);
```